# How to fill a b-table whit v-slot:cell() template Vue,js - BootstrapVue

Tags: javascript, api, vue.js, bootstrap-vue

The thing is that I make a table, filled with a REST api, here's the code

```
<template v-slot:cell(action)="{ products }">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col text-left">
        <h2>List</h2>

        <div class="col-md-12">
          <b-table striped hover :items="products" :fields="fields"></b-table>

          <template v-slot:cell(action)>
            <b-button size="sm" variant="primary">Edit</b-button>
            <b-button size="sm" variant="danger">Delete</b-button>
          </template>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from "axios";

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      fields: [
        { key: "name", label: "Title" },
        { key: "desc", label: "Desc" },
        { key: "action", label: "" }
      ],
      products: []
    };
  },
  methods: {
    getProducts() {
      const path = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1.0/products/";
      axios
        .get(path)
        .then(response => {
          this.products = response.data;
        })
        .catch(error => console.log(error));
    }
  },
  created() {
    this.getProducts();
  }
};
</script>
```

But the problem comes when I try to fill a column with Delete/Edit bootstrap buttons. I don't know why it happens and how to solve it with the Vue.js recently version

Comment: What version of Vue and Bootstrap-vue are you using?

Comment: I was thinking that it was the latest but I realize that is the 2.6.11. Anyways i don't know how to do it, Thanks for your help